# Json tuples to Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file with the following tuple format.

```
[[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],[4,"D"],[5,"E"]]
```

I am trying to turn into a dictionary in Python and get

```
{1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C", 4:"D", 5:"E"}
```

I am trying to use the following code

```
dict(json.loads(open('test.json')))
```

but keep getting following error

the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: how exactly are you trying?

Comment: `dict(my_list)`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `json` library to parse the string and pass the result to the `dict` constructor.

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '[[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],[4,"D"],[5,"E"]]'
>>> dict(json.loads(s))
{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E'}
```

If `s` is the content of a file, use `json.load`.